# After adding a column to Magento Sales order grid sorting and searching is not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added a column for the shipping method to the sales order grid. But now sorting and searching is not working for any of the column.I have 65 orders being listed at a time even if I select 20 from view drop-down.

I have created a custom module for this and I am getting correct values under shipping information column.

Following is my code in Grid.php file.

```
<?php
  class Mynamespace_Ordergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid  extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
    {      
        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
            $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_description'));
            $this->setCollection($collection);      
        }

        protected function _prepareColumns() {
             $this->addColumn('shipping_description', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
                'index' => 'shipping_description',
                'filter_index'=>'sales_flat_order.shipping_description',
             ));    
            return parent::_prepareColumns();  
        }   

        public function getGridUrl()
        {
            return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
        }
    }
?>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

muk,try below

```
      protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()->join(array('myorder'=>'sales_flat_order'),'main_table.entity_id=myorder.entity_id',array('myorder.shipping_method as  myorder_shipping_method'));

            $this->setCollection($collection);

            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
```

Columns view of

```
   $this->addColumn('myorder_shipping_method', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'myorder_shipping_method',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => $this->toOptionArray(),
    ));
```

add new function

```
public function toOptionArray($isMultiSelect = false)
{
    $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();

    $options = array();

    foreach($methods as $_code => $_method)
    {
        if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_code/title"))
            $_title = $_code;
        $options[$_code.'_'.$_code] = $_title . " ($_code)";
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me and I am getting blank column fot the shipping.

Comment: I am getting following with the new code you provided SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'myorder_shipping_method' in 'where clause'.  I wan to get the shipping detail in the text form.